# SQL Azure automated backup fails on a DB which has been deleted - cannot remove backup task

Tags: sql, backup, azure-sql-database, sql-azure-alerts

UPDATE:
I was able to contact the SQL Azure team and they are prioritizing the bug.  Hoping for a solution soon and will update here when I hear back.

While testing the new automated Export function in SQL Azure, I set a test database to backup nightly.  When this test was complete, I deleted the test database, but the automated export task still attempts to run nightly and floods my team with emails regarding the failure of this orphaned database.  Is there any way to delete the export job, or perhaps at least suppress the bogus alert?

How to repro:

1. Create a blank SQL Azure DB
2. Turn on automatic export.
3. Wait 48 hours to see a couple of exports successfully occur
4. Delete the test database created in step 1

Desired result: Export task is deleted/disabled and does not attempt to make an export nightly.  No alert emails are sent.

Actual Result: Export task on the deleted database is attempted nightly and a failure email is sent to my team nightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from SQL Azure team:

> Hello,
>
> We have investigated the issue and should have a fix soon. In the
>   meantime I would recommend creating a filter for these emails. Once
>   the fix is rolled out you can remove the filter (I will respond back
>   to this thread once it is).
>
> If you do not want to receive any failure emails you can opt-out
>   permanently via the Unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email. Note,
>   however, that this is permanent and will apply to all export failure
>   emails: once you have opted out there is no way to opt back in later.
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience,
>   -Stephen

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have resurfaced in another form: after in-place update to V12 disabling the auto export feature from the Azure management portal has no effect. It still tries to export the database and due to another bug in the feature - it fails.

Database copies are created and appear in the SQL Databases list (#Workspaces/SqlAzureExtension/Databases), however, they are not moved to the designated storage.

Manual copy/export operations via Azure management portal succeed. Also, manual export of "stuck" autoexport databases succeeds.

> Start Time: Wednesday, March 04, 2015 9:10:38 PM
> End Time: Wednesday, March 04, 2015 9:11:03 PM
> Subscription ID: [SUBSCRIPTION_ID]
> Server Name: [SERVER_NAME]
> Database Name: AutomatedSqlExport_[DATABASE_NAME]_20150304T100001Z
> Operation Name: Export
> Operation ID: 0baf208f-77d9-416d-b076-782a234af4f4
> Status: Failed
> Details: Error encountered during the service operation.
>
> Could not extract package from specified database.
>
> Unable to reconnect to database: Cannot open database "AutomatedSqlExport_[DATABASE_NAME]_20150304T100001Z" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user '[DATABASE_ADMIN_USER]'.
>
> Cannot open database "AutomatedSqlExport_[DATABASE_NAME]_20150304T100001Z" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user '[DATABASE_ADMIN_USER]'.